# Why is halving the best time for block size increase hard fork?

Tags: blockchain-fork, block-size-increase

Gavin Andresen said the best time to launch the block size increase update / hard fork would be the next reward halving (when mining discovery bounty would go from 25btc to 12.5btc).
Why has halving anything to do with increasing odds of success of a hard fork?

Source: Gaving Andersen said that at the Dev Core conference London on April 19th in his keynote "Why we need a bigger chain". There was a live broadcast of the event but I can't find a video link.

Comment: It would be good to include a link to where he says that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of months prior to a reward halving, the entire community is awake and excited about its prospects:  this has happened not only with bitcoin but will the other alt-chains out there.  So at this moment, bitcointalk, reddit, and most everyone is ready to listen and *actually upgrade*.  At other moments, many people might "just be going on with their lives" and not following the news.

Technically, due to bitcoin's and other alt-coins successful reward-halvings, there are slim chances of major issues in the reward-half process. That codebase is extremely solid.

It's especially important that *miners* upgrade, or a hardfork will be created, with all the possible inconsistencies that could happen, drop in computational power, not to mention user confusion and trust in the network.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely no reason for that from a technical perspective. Success is entirely dependent on convincing all the wallets, nodes, and lastly miners in the network to make a breaking change to their software.